# How to check code coverage delta in gitlab?

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, jacoco, gitlab-ce

Is there a way to check code coverage delta of gradle multiproject using JaCoCo on every merge request in GitLab CE and fail the pipeline if coverage level decreases?

Answer (score 2):

GitLab has Code Quality support built-in via Code Climate. If you run the code quality tests on both the target (usually master) and source branches then GitLab will display code quality degradation on the merge request.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/code_quality.html for an animated GIF of the feature plus more information. Further, you can find examples on how to set up a code quality job at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_quality.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately Code Quality is available only in Starter/Bronze and higher editions, while I'm using Community one.